# I don't know my SSH key passphrase cause Keychain managed it (pre-Sierra). What do I do now?

Tags: password, keychain, ssh

After Sierra update, a [new bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/27348363) was found where `ssh-agent` no longer remembers the passphrase for keys added. Not surprised by their answer, Apple stated **TL;DR: is not a bug, but a feature**.

Many threads I've read revolves around using `ssh-agent -A/-K` but the problem is not the loading, but that I never wrote my passphrase down anywhere.

What do I do now? Can I retrieve my passphrase from Keychain?

PD: **The reason I don't know my passphrase is** the whole point of the setup was not to write down a passphrase but let keychain manage it in order to centralize passwords, as I followed some best practiced (I think it was GitHub's?) where they mentioned "using easy to remember passphrases are easy to crack; using random letters/number/symbols are hard to remember so you most likely will write it down, which is also insecure. The solution is letting keychain manage it" or something like that.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found this https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-recover-my-ssh-key-passphrase/.  Leaving this open in case anybody panic as I did.

Comment: Done, will accept it in 2 days as there is that restriction

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just found [this](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-recover-my-ssh-key-passphrase/) Leaving this open in case anybody panic as I did.

**Steps:**

1. Open Keychain
2. Search for "SSH"
3. Double click on the SSH file you want
4. Select **Show password** on the bottom-left corner
5. Unlock your keychain with the administrative password.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree. I updated my answer to include the steps.